# Use Inheritance to Add More Restrictions on The Method Input

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

As title. I'm new to TS and learning it. I will provide an example to describe where I got stuck. The error of the code below is:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

So TS doesn't have the contextual knowledge: it doesn't know that the `push` of NumberQueue will restrict what can go into the queue.

```
// 11. Generics
// 
class Queue {
  private data = [];
  push(item) { this.data.push(item); }
  pop() { return this.data.shift(); }
}
class NumberQueue extends Queue {
  push(item: number) { super.push(item); }
  pop2(): number { return super.pop(); }  // I'm concerning the TS Error (as above) on this line.
}
```

How do I change the code to bypass this error? Given that I'm (assumed to be) more knowledgeable than TS. Another minor question is that is it possible to change `pop2` to `pop` without TS error?

Comment: You said your `pop2` method returned `number` but you actually return the result of [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) which is `undefined` because called on an `Array<never>`

Comment: I'd use generics; Change it to `Queue<T>`, with `data: T[]`, `push(item: T)`, and `pop(): T`. Then `NumberQueue` can just extend `Queue<number>`. I'm not sure why `pop` shifts in the base class and pops in the descendant though. Seems weird.

Comment: @GuerricP: While I also wrote that `push(...)` now accepts one with type `number`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and fix the method and `data` types like this:

```
class Queue<T> {
  private data: T[] = [];
  push(item: T) { this.data.push(item); }
  pop(): T | undefined { return this.data.shift(); }
}

class NumberQueue extends Queue<number> {
  push(item: number) { super.push(item); }
  pop2(): number | undefined { return super.pop(); } 
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECKCuBTJAeAKgPmgbwLAChpoAHAJwEsA3MAF0WgBNawAuaNAbQF1oBeabgG4CRYvAgALABTk6AWzZoAlDmg0J5CADomNMFrGSZ8pYOgBfESQD2xKUsXQAPtHgA7BogBm5N4gaqpIg08KRuahrauvqS5F409maW%20MkEoJAwAHLwcgBGiKQIyPSIAB50HjBFqG45%20aRYeIQk4tKyiArQtXkFKtjQEPDEBQatxh2mFlbEtgBM9mzd9c6uHt6%20-oHBoeGDw6QGtokW0ATmQA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I'm actually watching a tutorial which introduces generics. But I'm still interested that without generics (sorry I didn't mention this in my OP), how would the problem be solved?

Comment: Without generics you still have to type `Queue`, otherwise `data` is considered an `Array<never>` so you'd have to type everything as `number`. If you need a generic class, don't try not to type it at all, simply use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) this is their whole purpose

Comment: Then with your explanation, I will consider using inheritance not even considered a solution to the question in my title.

Comment: Indeed, a generic class is enough unless you want to add other methods on it but if you only want to type `pop` then you don't need to extend it